# Weird characters being outputed on my page

Tags: html, output

This problem seems to be rearing its ugly head again. I've include code and screenshot.

Every time I refresh the page, these weird characters seem to output to the text area on my page (see screenshot) and every time I refresh it seems to grow.

I've tried "minifying" code and that seemed to take care of the problem part of the time. Some people said it's a UTF-8 problem and while I'm not an expert at this, I'm using mediatemple and I'm pretty sure everything's been setup properly by default. ? Unless if I'm not doing something on my end.

FYI I copied and pasted my exported code from Webflow and majority of other pages seem to be fine.

Also the weird characters appear in the source code but they were never a part of the original code. It started to appear everytime I would refresh my page.

Please help

Brian

[image]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- This site was created in Webflow. http://www.webflow.com-->
<!-- Last Published: Tue Sep 23 2014 18:57:25 GMT+0000 (UTC) -->
<html data-wf-site="5359ea800548c9ed4700023a" data-wf-page="53862c5a1147a3793958c8f6">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bloomh MVP - Home2</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="generator" content="Webflow">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/webflow.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bloomhmvp.webflow.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.4.7/webfont.js"></script>
  <script>
    WebFont.load({
      google: {
        families: ["Bitter:400,700,400italic","Droid Serif:400,700","Carme:regular","Roboto Slab:300,regular,700","Nixie One:regular","Pontano Sans:regular","Quicksand:300,regular,700","Muli:300,300italic,regular,italic","Raleway:300,regular,500,600,700,800,900","Arimo:regular,italic,700,700italic","Oxygen:300,regular,700","Cabin:regular,italic,500,500italic,600,600italic,700,700italic","Roboto:300,300italic,regular,italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic"]
      }
    });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/fontawesome-webfont.svg">
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="w-nav navbar" data-collapse="medium" data-animation="default" data-duration="400">
    <div class="w-clearfix navbar-section">
      <div class="w-clearfix logo-container">
        <a class="w-nav-brand logo" href="index.html"></a><a class="brand" href="index.html">Bloomh</a>
      </div>
      <nav class="w-nav-menu navmenu-open" role="navigation"><a class="w-nav-link nav-links" href="category.html">Submit Need</a><a class="w-nav-link nav-links" href="faq.html">FAQ</a><a class="w-nav-link nav-links" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      </nav>
      <div class="w-nav-button menu-button">
        <div class="w-icon-nav-menu"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hero-background home2">
    <div class="w-container hero-container">
      <h1 class="hero-tagline home2 mobile">Brides set the price<br>Vendors come to them</h1>
      <div class="w-row hero-row">
        <div class="w-col w-col-6">
          <h2 class="w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny secondary-tagline home2">A new way to hire&nbsp;<br>photographers &amp; videographers</h2>
          <div class="w-hidden-main w-hidden-medium secondary-tagline mobile">A new way to hire photographers &amp; videographers</div>
          <div class="more-categories-coming home2">more categories coming soon...</div>
        </div>
        <div class="w-col w-col-6"><a class="button join-button main-top" href="get-started.html">Get Started!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="more-categories">Birthdays / Portraits / Parties / Bat Mitzvahs / Engagements</div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-container vendor-benefit-container">
    <div class="vendor-benefits main">Are you a photographer/videographer?
      <br><span style="font-size: 14px;"></span>
    </div><a class="benefits-link" href="vendor-welcome.html">See Benefits</a>
    <div class="w-hidden-main w-hidden-medium w-hidden-small how-to-box phone">
      <div class="vendor-how-to phone">Sign Up</div>
      <div class="fa fa-chevron-down"></div>
      <div class="vendor-how-to phone">Get Clients via Email</div>
      <div class="fa fa-chevron-down"></div>
      <div class="vendor-how-to phone">Free and Easy!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-hidden-tiny how-to-box main">
      <div class="vendor-how-to">Sign Up</div>
      <div class="fa fa-chevron-right"></div>
      <div class="vendor-how-to">Get clients in your inbox</div>
      <div class="fa fa-chevron-right"></div>
      <div class="vendor-how-to">Free and Easy!</div>
    </div><a class="sign-up-now" href="vendor-welcome.html">Sign up Now!</a>
  </div>
  <div class="w-container middle-container side-border">
    <div class="hr small how-work"></div>
    <div class="how-it-works home">How it Works</div>
    <div class="hr small how-work-bottom"></div>
    <div class="w-row middle-row">
      <div class="w-col w-col-6">
        <h3 class="benefit-title">Brides Set the Price&nbsp;</h3>
        <div class="benefit-description">You control your budget. Tell us what you can afford to pay and describe your need.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="w-col w-col-6">
        <img class="w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny imagesizetest" src="images/moneyfinish2.jpg" alt="53b469e62a45851e74e825a8_moneyfinish2.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-hidden-main w-hidden-medium fa fa-chevron-down"></div>
    <img class="w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny arrow1" src="images/arrow3 copy.gif" width="110" alt="535ebf2013322e38680001d3_arrow3%20copy.gif">
    <div class="w-row middle-row">
      <div class="w-col w-col-6 w-clearfix">
        <img class="w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny right-justify imagesize" src="images/networkfinish.jpg" alt="53b46a4a75641b72645198f0_networkfinish.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="w-col w-col-6">
        <h3 class="benefit-title">Bloomh's Network</h3>
        <div class="benefit-description">We reach into our vast network of qualified vendors with your request. All vendors are experienced &amp; highly talented in their craft.&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-hidden-main w-hidden-medium fa fa-chevron-down"></div>
    <img class="w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny arrow2" src="images/arrow1 copy.gif" width="120" alt="535ebea213322e38680001cb_arrow1%20copy.gif">
    <div class="w-row middle-row">
      <div class="w-col w-col-6">
        <h3 class="benefit-title">Pre-Approved Vendors</h3>
        <div class="benefit-description">Only wedding vendors who agree on your price and eager to work within your budget will contact you!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="w-col w-col-6">
        <img class="w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny thumbs-image" src="images/thumbsup1finish.jpg" alt="53b46aaa2a45851e74e825bb_thumbsup1finish.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-hidden-main w-hidden-medium fa fa-chevron-down"></div>
    <img class="w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny arrow3" src="images/arrow2 copy.gif" width="110" alt="535ebe1fd5d3ba3b68000210_arrow2%20copy.gif">
    <div class="w-row middle-row">
      <div class="w-col w-col-6 w-clearfix">
        <img class="w-hidden-small w-hidden-tiny right-justify guarantee-image" src="images/sealfinish.jpg" alt="53b1db8cddca344949a6d8ee_sealfinish.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="w-col w-col-6">
        <h3 class="benefit-title">Bloomh Guarantee</h3>
        <div class="benefit-description">Brides pay a small one-time fee (free for vendors). If you're not happy weÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€ Ã¢â‚¬â„¢ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ã‚Â¬Ãƒâ€¦Ã‚Â¡ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¬ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ã‚Â¬Ãƒâ€¦Ã‚Â¾ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ll find new vendors free of charge or return your money back. No questions asked! &nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size: 15px;"><em><u>More Info</u></em></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><div class="w-container middle-container side-border dark"><div class="testimonial">Testmonials</div><div class="hr"></div><div class="testimonial-text">â€œI can't believe how easy it was. Bloomh found me my perfect wedding photographer and at the price that I chose. Crazy!â€</div><div class="testimonial-user main">- Patty Lawson, Corona CA <br>(Bride)</div><div class="testimonial-text">â€œI use Bloomh to get most of my new wedding clients. It plays a big part in growing my business.â€</div><div class="testimonial-user main">- Lance Capshaw, Huntington Beach CA <br>(Vendor)</div><div class="testimonial-text">â€œEvery bride who is planning their wedding needs to give Bloomh a try!â€</div><div class="testimonial-user main">- Sarah Baxter, Los Angeles CA <br>(Bride)</div><a class="button join-button center" href="get-started.html">Get Started!</a><a class="vendor-sign-up" href="vendor-welcome.html">Vendor Sign Up!</a></div>
  <div class="footer-background main"><a class="footer-link" href="terms-use.html">Terms of Use</a><a class="footer-link" href="faq.html">FAQ</a><a class="footer-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    <div class="social-container phone">
      <div class="w-embed w-iframe facebook-icon">
        <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.com%2Fbloomhpage&amp;width=100&amp;layout=button&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=true&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:35px;"
        allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="w-widget w-widget-twitter social-icon tweet">
        <iframe src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html#url=http%3A%2F%2FBloomh.com&amp;counturl=Bloomh.com&amp;text=At%20%40Bloomh%2C%20Brides%20set%20the%20price%20%26%20Vendors%20come%20to%20them.%20I%20love%20it!&amp;count=none&amp;size=m&amp;dnt=true"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="border: none; overflow: hidden; width: 55px; height: 20px;"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="w-widget w-widget-twitter social-icon tweet follow">
        <iframe src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets/follow_button.html#screen_name=bloomh&amp;show_count=false&amp;size=m&amp;show_screen_name=true&amp;dnt=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="border: none; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 20px;"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inc">Bloomh Inc. 2014.</div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/webflow.js"></script>
  <!--[if lte IE 9]><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/placeholders/3.0.2/placeholders.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are probably getting the weird characters in your output because they are in your code. I can see them in the html you posted.

Comment: In the following line, `<div class="benefit-description">Brides pay a small one-time fee (free for vendors). If you're not happy weÃƒÆ’Ã†...`, I am assuming the text starts going *bad* at an **apostrophe in the word "we'll"**  - is this assumption correct?  If so, you may have a back-tick instead of a simple apostrophe?

Comment: The weird characters are in the HTML source and result from character encoding errors (typically, UTF-8 misinterpreted as windows-1252). From the data given in the question, it is impossible to infer where the mess comes from.

Comment: No...the weird characters were never in the original code. It started to develop everytime I would refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line of code:

```
<div class="benefit-description">Brides pay a small one-time fee (free for vendors). If you're not happy weÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€ Ã¢â‚¬â„¢ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ã‚Â¬Ãƒâ€¦Ã‚Â¡ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¬ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ã‚Â¬Ãƒâ€¦Ã‚Â¾ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ll find new vendors free of charge or return your money back. No questions asked! &nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size: 15px;"><em><u>More Info</u></em></span>
```

As you can see, those characters are set right on code, this happens frequently for 2 reasons.
1.- You copy/paste that text from another non-plain-text editor and webflow did not understand the "text language" of that particular parragraph.

2.- As you said before, an encoding problem, try to use a plain-text editor to write the text you want (I recomend sublime text) and save it as UTF-8 .txt (extension does not matter really, but is also good practice). and then replace the text in between `<div class="benefit-description">...and...<span style="font-size: 15px;">`

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the help. First of all the weird characters were never in the original source code. It started to develop everytime I would refresh the page. Also I used webflow to design and build and then exported. I took the export and did a straight upload. I did not copy and paste after export from webflow.

Comment: I hope that made sense. So I didnt "write" any code inside webflow. Webflow is a very clean drag n drop UI builder. I then exported code and did straight upload to hosting.